# Trapped in the "Configuring ttf-mscorefonts-installer"

Tags: wine, software-installation

I finally installed Wine (the program to run exe files) and it took a very long time to install.

Now, I have a package configuration window that is pink and looks like this

[image] .

I don't know what to do at this point and I can not exit out of that window without the whole installation failing and then messing up my sudo apt-get install commands.

I tried hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> but nothing works.

I've clicked all around the screen too and still, nothing works.  PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Have you tried pressing Shift+Tab? I believe that should work. Had the same problem a while back.

Answer (score 3):

On screens like this, <kbd>tab</kbd> cycles forward through the fields. <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> cycles backward. You should be able to hit <kbd>tab</kbd> once or twice to get to the `OK` field, then continue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to install it from the command line. I tried to do it the same way and ran into this problem. If you use the Ubuntu Software Center, you will get a yes/no contract and you will be able to use the mouse. I hope this helps.